# How do i implement printing to stdout in my custom language?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am currently making a Compiler for my own Programming Language in C# using [LLVMSharp](https://github.com/Microsoft/LLVMSharp) and I've wondered how to implement printing to stdout, stderr, and getting input from stdin. I've looked at the source code for Haskell(GHC) and Rust(rustc) but it was a bit too different/complex for me...

Please note that I do not want to link an existing function for it like printf or anything of the like.

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this to me, or at least point me in the direction of a tutorial/guide concerning this problem.

Comment: "Please note that I do not want to link an existing function for it like printf or anything of the like." Why not? If you don't link to libc (or some other library), you'll have to write system-specific code for every platform you want to support. To the best of my knowledge both GHC's and Rust's standard library link against libc.

Comment: @sepp2k I see... then how do I reference stdout, etc from there and work with them?

Comment: You'd define `stdout` and other global variables as `extern global` and use `declare` for any functions you need. [Like this](https://gist.github.com/sepp2k/c38426affa77df6275e6cda12ac30dc0) (of course this could have been more easily implemented just using `puts` instead of `fputs`, but you asked specifically about `stdout`, so I've made an example that used `stdout`).

Comment: Oh, this helps me a lot thank you!!